# Are 3D printed containers safe for cosmetics?

Tags: safety, sla

So I've seen info about food-safe 3D printed containers, but I haven't seen anything about safety when it comes to containers used for cosmetics.

Would a cured resin 3D printed jar be safe for holding lotion or cosmetic creams?

I know the FDA has rules around containers that come in contact with food, but I haven't seen anything about cosmetics.

Comment: I can provide a guidance document of the cosmetics manufacturers to others: https://cosmeticseurope.eu/download/UG14b1RFS01qdlllbFBwdTZlRXRwdz09 and the FDA runs a registration program https://www.fda.gov/cosmetics/voluntary-cosmetic-registration-program - and there's a norm https://www.iso.org/standard/36436.html

Comment: @Trish thanks for this. it's really informative. the main thing I'm wondering is if anyone knows of things in the resin leeching into things like lotion or creams?